# Why do I get a compilation error "expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘=’ token"?

Tags: c

Here is a code snippet

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *readline();
char **split_string(char *);

// Complete the sockMerchant function below.
int sockMerchant(int n, int ar_count, int ar = [1,2,3]) {
    n = 12;
    char pairs = n / sizeof(ar);
    return pairs;
}
```

There are three functions that follow i.e the main, plus two others to read line and split char.

Comment: C doesn't have default function arguments.

Comment: This function comes from a Hackerrank challenge, so where it says "Complete the sockMerchant function below", you were probably already given a correct function skeleton. You're supposed to use the exact function you were given, because the judge needs to call it. You can change only the function body, that is what's between the curly braces `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has problems:

- there are no default argument values in C, `int ar = [1,2,3]` makes no sense. This argument should probably be defined as `int *ar`
- `n = 12;` overwrites the argument value.
- it is unclear what your intent is with `char pairs = n / sizeof(ar);`

Comment: `char pairs = n / sizeof(ar);` - he probably wants to get the length of the array

Comment: @Programmer: not really, the length of the array could be `ar_count`. The name `pairs` indicates something else, but the `char` type is inconsistent. And it is unclear what the arguments are.